# Let $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$. Sequence in image converges, prove convergence of the function at a given value in the sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, continuity

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Assume $f$ is increasing. Assume $f(1) = 2$.
Assume the sequence $2 + (−1)^n/n$ belongs to the image of $f$. Prove that $f$ is continuous at $1$.

Should I just show the sequence converges to $2$? Or show it is a cluster point and use the sequential characterization of sequences? If so, how would I show that?

Comment: @John. Ahh misread! Deleted as to not add confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing a proof, let me give you the idea why this is true.

Fix an even $n$. Then you know that there is $x_n$ so that $f(x_n) = 2 + \frac 1n$. This $x_n$ is $> 1$, since $f$ is increasing. Again as $f$ is increasing, we have for all $y$ in $[1, x_n]$,

$$f(1) \le f(y) \le f(x_n) \Rightarrow 2 \le f(y) \le 2 + \frac 1n.$$

That is, $f(y)$ is closed to $2$ when $y$ is closed to $1$ (at least on the right, but you can also argue for $y<1$, using an odd $n$). This is the intuitive reason why $f$ is continuous at $1$.

Comment: When proving $f(y)$ converges to 2, should I use a delta-epsilon proof on each side?

Comment: You need to use an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof. Don't understand what you mean by "on each side" @User52525